# How to achieve the below scenario using java?

Tags: java

I need to achieve the below scenario through java logic.

RECORDS  PCCVALUE  INVENTORY
  Rec1         1          1

Rec2         1           5

Rec3         1             3

Rec4           2            6

Rec5          2             10

In the above scenario the records need to be sort first based on PCCVALUE ascending order and if all the PCCVALUE are same then it's need to be sort based on inventory value in descending order.

For eg in the first three records PCCVALUE is 1 so out of this three records the output need to be come like below based on inventory sorting descending order and then the last two records having PCC value is 2 and it's inventory was sorted based on descending order,

RECORDS  PCCVALUE  INVENTORY

Rec2      1         5

Rec3      1         3

Rec1      1         1

Rec5      2         10

Rec4      2         6

Can anyone provide the java code logic to achieve this scenario. Waiting for the response.

Comment: Thats easy, you write a custom `Comparator` that provides the desired ordering. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: Write your own comparators.. This is called Invariance and Covariance. If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom `Comparator` you can achieve this like below,

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Rec1 1 1", "Rec2 1 5", "Rec3 1 3", "Rec4 2 6", "Rec5 2 10)");
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String one, String two) {
                return Integer.valueOf(one.split(" ")[1]).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(two.split(" ")[1]));
            }
        });
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```